# Hashset<string>contains for collection

Tags: c#

I am comparing 2 hashsets full of filenames.I have successfully implemented "ExceptWith" but now I need to get a list of "all filenames that are in both sets."

I know hashset has a contains but that means looping the hashset for each item of the other one.
Wondering if there is an inbuilt method to do this.
I am doing with files with over 50000 filenames.

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is a set intersection. There is a built in method for that:

```
HashSet<string> x = new HashSet<string> { "x", "a","b"};
HashSet<string> y = new HashSet<string> { "z", "a","b"};
x.IntersectWith(y);
```

Note that this modifies the original HashSet `x`. If you don't want that, use the extension method on Enumerable:

```
var intersection = x.Intersect(y);
```

Since the last one is defined as an extension on `IEnumerable<T>`, it works on the more general case as well. Just be aware that it might not be as optimized for performance as `HashSet<T>.IntersectWith`, since it needs to be able to work on all enumerables.

Comment: hi,that worked.Need to wait few mins to accept the answer but that worked.Thanks.